# Using constants from other modules

Tags: angularjs

Why am I able to use a constant defined in module A while I am in module B without defining dependency on module A ?!

```
angular.module("A", ["B"])
            .constant("con",10)
            .run(function(con){
                console.log(con);
            })

    angular.module("B",[])
            .run(function (con){//why can i use this here no dependency on A!!
                console.log(con); 
            })
```

Comment: same reason that directives or services from different modules that are added to main module are available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because what matters is the whole set of transitive dependencies of the root module (i.e. your application module). All the angular components are in a single namespace containing all the components of all the modules on which the root module depends on, transitively.

So, in your example, if the application module is A, then it contains the constant "con", which is available from any of the transitive dependencies of A.

Comment: so if my modules is like that: `main`, `dependsOnOther`, `Other`. I dont need to add `Other` as dependency to `dependsOnOther` to use `Other` filters in `dependsOnOterh`. I can just have both of them to be dependecies to the `main` module and now all modules can use each others commponents? so basically i can skip adding dependency on other modules than the  application module?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just remember that you'll also have to do it in unit tests, every time you load the modules. For example, if you test a component of dependsOnOther that actually needs a component of Other, the unit test will have to load both modules. If you keep the dependency, you can only load dependsOnOther.